# Next.js Internationalized Routing: Production build error: Error occurred prerendering page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js

I've the following next.config.js:

```
module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'es'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    localeDetection: false,
  },
  ...
});
```

That enables routes for locales *en* and *es* being *en* the default locale.

In the root of the project lives `_posts/en` and `_post/es` holding the `.md` files for the dynamic post pages.

I see everything working fine when I run the dev script `"dev": "next dev"` being able to switch between both locales with no problem and navigate through pages.

But if I run the prod script  `"build-prod": "run-s clean build export"` being the scrips called within the following: `"clean": "rimraf .next out"`, `"build": "build": "next build"`, `"export": "next export"`

then I get the following errors:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/en/posts/[slug]"
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'undefined')

Error occurred prerendering page "/en/posts/[slug]"
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'undefined')

> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /posts/[slug]: /en/posts/[slug]
    /posts/[slug]: /es/posts/[slug]
```

Does anyone know what could be different between dev and prod that could cause this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your [slug] code

Comment: The issue is more complex than I thought. After solving the TypeError I found the real issue when running the prod script again: "18n support is not compatible with next export". I see that there are many open discussions about the problem and I'm trying to find what suits me best: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18957

Comment: I ended up solving the issue following this approach: https://dev.to/adrai/static-html-export-with-i18n-compatibility-in-nextjs-8cd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently i18n support is not compatible with static HTML export so I decided to drop it.

Instead, I decided to implement my own solution for internationalised routing.

I used `next-language-detector` to handle language detection and redirect from the index page in my Next.js project to the content in the preferred language.

To manage the content I enabled a route for each language adding directories with the language code under `pages/`. In my case `es` and `en`. Each directory will read the translated data stored in markdown.

For a similar approach see this article: https://dev.to/adrai/static-html-export-with-i18n-compatibility-in-nextjs-8cd